# Mapreduce - retain input order

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

File having list of numbers separated by pipeline, can have duplicates. Need to write map reduce program to list out numbers with out duplicate in original input order. Am able to remove duplicates but it doesn't retain input order.

Comment: Why not use Hive, Pig, or Spark to do this? Each can do this in less than 10 lines of code

Comment: Okay, then force the data to one reducer and sort it

Comment: It's not clear if you're being given input data that's sorted already, or rather you're being asked to preserve the exact order of input data, just without duplicates

Comment: yes need to preserve input order. basically the input data not in any order.

Comment: as of now my output is like ( key=number, val= order_position). i think i need to make it key=order_position, val=number so that it preserves the input order. [ in mapper i m assining order_position sequence number to the numbers]

Comment: Please edit your question to include your input data, code as a [mcve], and expected output

Comment: i will add later my code

Comment: @baidyas I have added the pseudo code, hope it helps.

Comment: solved the issue with two mapreduce jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very simple, Suppose your text is :

```
Line 1 -> On the top of the Crumpetty Tree
Line 2 -> The Quangle Wangle sat,
Line 3 -> But his face you could not see,
Line 4 -> On account of his Beaver Hat.
Line 5 -> But his face you could not see,
Line 6 -> The Quangle Wangle sat,
```

Where `Line 2` and `3` are repeating at `line 5` and `6`.

The mapper should be similar to `wordcount` program, where input to the mapper is something like

**key-value pairs:**

```
(0, On the top of the Crumpetty Tree)
(33, The Quangle Wangle sat,)
(57, But his face you could not see,)
(89, On account of his Beaver Hat.)
(113, But his face you could not see,)
(146, The Quangle Wangle sat,)
```

**The output of the mapper**

```
(NullWritable, 0_On the top of the Crumpetty Tree)
(NullWritable, 33_The Quangle Wangle sat,)
(NullWritable, 57_But his face you could not see,)
(NullWritable, 89_On account of his Beaver Hat.)
(NullWritable, 113_But his face you could not see,)
(NullWritable, 146_The Quangle Wangle sat,)
```

Now, make sure that you have only one reducer, such that the input of the single reducer would be

**Input to reducer**

```
Key: NullWritable
Iterable<value>: [(0_On the top of the Crumpetty Tree), 
(33_The Quangle Wangle sat,), 
(57_But his face you could not see,), 
(89_On account of his Beaver Hat.), 
(113_But his face you could not see,), 
(146_The Quangle Wangle sat,)]
```

Note that the input to the reducer is sorted in *ascending* order, and in this case it maintains the original order because the `offset` to line in `TextInputFormat` is always in `ascending` order.

In the reducer, just iterate through the list, weed out duplicates and write the line after removing the `offset` and the `_` delimiter at the start. The reducer output would something like:

**Reducer key-value**

```
NullWritable, value.split("_")[1]
```

**Output from reducer**

```
Line 1 -> On the top of the Crumpetty Tree
Line 2 -> The Quangle Wangle sat,
Line 3 -> But his face you could not see,
Line 4 -> On account of his Beaver Hat.
```